# HTML5 video player seek bar not working

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have embedded html5 video player in my application. When I open the web page for the first time, then video player seek bar doesn't work. If I refresh the page and seek the video then it works fine.

```
    function seekToTime(value) {
    var vidPlayer = $("#myVideo")[0];
    var seekToTime = value;
    if (seekToTime < 0 || seekToTime > vidPlayer.duration)
        return; 

    vidPlayer.currentTime = seekToTime;
    $("#myVideo")[0].play();

}
```

Comment: When does seekToTime() get called? Chances are that the first time the HTML5 video has not loaded yet, however the second time it is pulling out of cache so its faster hence working.

Comment: works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/NpgD5/481/